# "В верх" и "вверх"

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Когда **в верх** пишется раздельно, а когда **вверх** — слитно?

Comment: Слитно, так правильно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда слово отвечает на вопрос "куда", пишется слитно.
Пример: *"полететь вверх"*.
Когда есть определямое слово и между "в" и "верх" можно вставить еще одно слово, то раздельно.
Пример: "*в (самый) верх листа*"

Answer (score 1):

**Вверх** — это наречие, следовательно, пишется слитно.
Необходимо отличать наречия от существительных с предлогом. Для этого надо подумать над смыслом выражения и определить, можно ли задать вопросы, есть ли зависимость слов друг от друга.
**Взлететь** (куда?) **вверх** — нет поясняющего слова, поэтому это наречие, пишем слитно. **Посмотреть в верх** (чего?) **горы** — пишем раздельно, потому что поясняется *в верх чего именно*?
Так же поступаем и со словами *вглубь, вширь, вниз* и т. д.